# In Java, among an array of objects, is there a way to change only one object's variable?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to Java (honestly programming altogether), and have been testing out some stuffs.

I defined a class (say Nest), in which the class is defined by another class (say Nested), and the "Nested" class saves a variable(say a). So a "Nest" class saves a nested class, which saves a variable.

I needed multiple objects of the class Nest, so I defined an array of Nests, tried to modify only nest[0].nested.a, and not nest[i].nested.a. However, it turns out all the other objects that belong to this array's varibales have also been modified.

This is what I tried:

```
class Test{
    public static class Nested{
        static int a;
        Nested(int a){
            this.a = a;
        }
    }
    public static class Nest{
        Nested nested;
        Nest(Nested nested){    
            this.nested = nested;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Nest [] nest = new Nest[2];
        Nested nested = new Nested(0);

        nest[0] = new Nest(nested); //nest[0].nested.a = 0
        nest[1] = new Nest(nested); //nest[1].nested.a = 0
        System.out.println(nest[0].nested.a + "\t" + nest[1].nested.a);

        nest[0].nested.a = 1;
                //Also tried nest[0].nested = new Nested(1); but didn't make a difference
        System.out.println(nest[0].nested.a + "\t" + nest[1].nested.a);
    }
}
```

Expectations were:

```
0    0
1    0
```

But got the results:

```
0    0
1    1
```

Would there be a way to get the expected results while keeping the array? Thanks.

Comment: Why is Nested.a static?

Comment: since a is a static field, its value will be modified for all instance of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that both `Nest` classes have references to the same `Nested` instance. To get the behavior you want, you should create two `Nested` instances, one for each `Nest` array element.

Comment: Well that's *one* problem. Another is that `a` is static, so actually there's only a single `a`  variable regardless of how many instances of `Nested` there are.